# Enabling USB debugging with broken screen (is it possible to connect external screen via usb 2.0 OTG?)

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen, usb-on-the-go, external-display, asus-zenfone-3

The phone is Asus Zenfone 3 ZE553KL. The screen is black and touch is not working. The phone is locked with a pattern. Power, volume buttons and navigation bar at the bottom work. Is there any way to connect the device to a computer without replacing the screen?

I've read it is possible to connect the phone to external monitor and a mouse, but is there any adapter for usb-c 2.0 otg allowing to display the screen on external monitor?

Besides to use OTG it seems it has to be accepted on the touchscreen beforehand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_88baLPHdxo.

The phone wasn't rooted and no custom modifications were done to it.

Comment: Pattern is bad really bad, because the only way to solve it is by using a mouse connected via USB, but drawing the pattern blindly is next to impossible.

Comment: I see, then it seems the only real solution is to buy a new screen and to enable usb debugging just in case to be prepared for future. I see that many modern phones still use usb 2.0 port. Ugh, the current state of smartphone industry is disappointing then

Comment: My recommendation for the future: 1. don't use pattern, use pin instead. 2. Enable debugger menu and enable adb 3. On newer devices don't forget to enable the option "Disable adb authorization timeout". 4. On the PC make a backup of the file `~/.android/adbkey` and `~/.android/adbkey.pub` That is the best preparation for the next broken screen.